# Chrome suspended while self-updating

Tags: google-chrome, updates

Recently, I wanted to check if my Chrome  was the newest one.

So I clicked the "About Google Chrome" button, and it showed updating.  I closed the updating dialog and went back to the main UI.

I couldn't browse correctly anymore... things like closing a tab or opening a new tab - it totally seemed like Chrome suspended.

In the end, I had to stop the process in task manager.

Comment: Did it work correctly when you reopened it or after it finished updating?

Comment: it didn't work properly after I reopened it.
Looks like it's still running something, but after a few minutes later, it automatically updates to the newest version and works fine.